# Using NFT paired to credentials for identity verification

Tags: anonymity, identity, nft

I have a question on the feasibility of pairing a non fungible token (NFT) with credentials for identity verification on the Ethereum blockchain. Can we imagine a scenario where a user would have a unique NFT token assigned to him upon account creation on a platform, and that the credentials used to create the account, when re-used for logging in to the platform could match, and therefore retrieve the NFT? The process would take place in such a way that even the owner of the platform could not know what NFT is matching what account. That way, for any action performed on the platform, the user is identified by his NFT instead of his credentials (username or email) to preserve anonymity?

Additional note based on received answers: people would actually be registering with their identity cards on the platform to make sure that one person can't have more than one account. Another important point here, is that the owner of the platform should not be able to match the created account with the associated "transaction-maker" entity while by re logging-in with the same ID, the system should be able to do the association.

I know this may look like a dumb question, but any answer would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using credentials or an NFT, maybe just have the user interact with your application through their ethereum address / wallet. Any changes to this address's account in your application would require a signed blockchain transaction or a signed message from this account. This is the way many daps work today. The recommendation of your site would be that the user have a separate account they use only for interacting with your site / dapp to help maintain privacy across transactions / daps.

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for your answer, it's really appreciated. I realize I missed an important point in my question though. People would actually be registering with their identity cards on the platform to make sure that one person can't have more than one account. Another important point here, is that the owner of the platform should not be able to match the created account with the associated "transaction-maker" entity while by re logging-in with the same ID, the system should be able to do the association. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a trusted Identity Provider / Validator would be necessary to handle "authenticating" the provider ID doc. Once validated that party will would issue the NFT which is then presented and used for authenticating with your app.

Your app wouldn't care which NFT is which it just knows that entity X is now logged in from the information in the NFT.